# How to put PyCharm on web

Tags: web-applications, server, pycharm

I heard in some grad school labs they offer websites that allow the use of applications such as PyCharm or R studio once logged in.
The point is using the state-of-the-art server from your PC through internet.

I wondered how they put the whole application on web and started googling.

I was guessing like JetBrains provided API for that but I still don't know exactly how they did it.
Can anyone give me a help for this matter?

Comment: cloud platforms?

Comment: Would you kindly care to elaborate? Right now, I'm suspecting launching a VDI client on web.

Comment: I don't have any experience with it. Sorry about that.

Comment: O' welp. Thx anyways. And happy new year tho several days late :D